# Ember.js: Handlebars context switching with contentBinding of a view

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I had a tiny bit of code in a view:

```
{{#each itemController="category"}}


  {{! create a view and set the content to the current model in the loop }}
  {{view "category" contentBinding="this"}}

{{/each}}
```

As you may immediately notice, this is deprecated.
So I updated my code as such:

```
{{#each category in model itemController="category"}}

   {{! create a new view and set the content to the current model in the loop }}
   {{view "category" contentBinding="category"}}

{{/each}}
```

For some reason this is not the same. Because in my view the content context is lost. I used to do a `this.get('propery')` in my view, which is now broken.

In my view I have no special code related to the contentBinding. Not even a `contentBinding: 'content' line of code because this was never needed.

Comment: Is `model` defined and an array? Try using `this` instead of `model`.

Comment: @rogMaHall Thank you, and yes it is an array of objects (categories). You mean that I need to alter `contentBinding="category"` to `contentBinding="this"`? That does unfortunately not work.
@BuckDoyle What are your trying to type ;-)

Comment: @DelphiLynx Ok good. I should've been more clear. I meant try `this` in the `#each` instead of `model`, but really you should use `controller`. Is the template your showing working from an Ember.ArrayController?